# electron builder fails due to wrong dir path

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am building a electron app in github actions...

This works fine:
`electron-builder --x64 --publish never`

But this  don't: `electron-builder --x64`
Build fails

```
  • electron-builder  version=22.7.0 os=5.4.0-1020-azure
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • packaging       platform=linux arch=x64 electron=9.1.1 appOutDir=releases/linux/x64/linux-unpacked
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.1.1/electron-v9.1.1-linux-x64.zip size=73 MB parts=4
  • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.1.1/electron-v9.1.1-linux-x64.zip duration=1.219s
  • building        target=7z arch=x64 file=releases/linux/x64/PasswordTool
  • publishing      publisher=Github (owner: rockg688, project: rock_test, version: 0.0.0)
  ⨯ ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/rock_test/rock_test/PasswordTool_GUI/releases/linux/x64/PasswordTool'  stackTrace=Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/rock_test/rock_test/PasswordTool_GUI/releases/linux/x64/PasswordTool'
```

If we look closely `rock_test/rock_test` rock_test is repo folder.
But I don't know why it is repeating twice and how to fix it...

Comment: If you can attach your builder configuration and project structure, it will much better.